# Angular Html Css header is hidden in one of components

Tags: html, css, angular

My main app.component.html consists of 3 elements: app-header, router-outler and app-footer. I have a problem with showing component app-header in one of component.  It shows correctly in home (url: /home) but in endlessblow.component (url: /projects/endlessblow) not.  I guess there is a problem with my CSS in this component because when I removed all styles from this component the header appeared. The question is what styles elements should I use instead to get the same visual effect but with app-header additionaly. Full code is shown here [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wu9kht?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) if you need something more. The essential code looks like this:

app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

endlessblow.component.html

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content" [ngStyle]="{'bottom': footerHeight+10+'px'}"></div>
</div>
```

endlessblow.component.css

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
}

#content {
  border: 3px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  text-align:center;
  overflow: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Remove `position: absolute` from `#wrapper` and `#content`

Comment: @Minal Chauhan Header appeared but now wrapper is not full screen and this fragment: [ngStyle]="{'bottom': footerHeight+10+'px' } not work.

Comment: try adding this css : `header{position: relative;  z-index: 1;}` without removing `position: absolute` from `#wrapper` and `#content`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work :(

Comment: add `z-index: -1` in `#wrapper`

Comment: It works! I would give you best answer but as a comment I can not.

Comment: I have added an answer, so please accpet it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `#wrapper` div has `position: absolute` so that it hides the header. so that you need to add `z-index:-1` for `#wrapper`

```
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  z-index:-1
}
```